# AS3 Retrieve And Set Page URL From SWF

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I have seen more than a couple of sites using flash content and displaying it based on the URL string.

For example, accessing **http://domain.com/** loads the site normally and the SWF object displays the home page and sets the URL to **http://domain.com/#/home**. Then accessing the About section sets the URL to **http://domain.com/#/about**

Also, if accessing **http://domain.com/#/services** directly (from the browser's address bar), loads the site and the SWF displays the Services section automatically.

I would like to implement something similar to this as well. Could anyone tell me how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean "deep linking", and with Flash it is usually done using [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/). The website has a bunch of good examples to get you started.

Comment: Yes, deep linking. I didn't know it is called like that. Thank you and the user package for the information!